# Drupal 6 make a content edit form be in a specified theme

Tags: theming

This is in Drupal 6.

How to make a content edit form be in a specified theme?

The administration theme is 'seven', and use admin theme for content edit.
Site configuration: /admin/settings/admin
Administration theme: Seven
[x] Use administration theme for content edit

Create a new content type 'example'.

In the module, this function makes 'example' edit form in example_node_form.tpl.php template.
But this template will be in 'seven' theme, themes/seven/example_node_form.tpl.php

```
function modulename_theme() {
  return array(
    'example_node_form' => array(
    'template' => 'example-node-form',
    'render element' => 'form',
    ),
  );
}
```

Want 'example' edit form in another theme, not 'seven' theme?

How to make a content edit form be in a specified theme?

Answer (score 0):

Implement [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) in custom module and check for current theme :

```
global $theme;
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'example_node_form_id' && $theme != 'theme_machine_name') {
    // redirect anywhere using drupal_goto.
  }
}
```